# Android - Load image from gallery and set as background

Tags: android, image, background, gallery

I want to load an image from image gallery into my app and set this image as background.

This works fine with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select background"), SELECT_PICTURE);



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            Drawable bg;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                bg = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, selectedImageUri.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                bg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bg);
            }

            drawView.startNew();
            drawView.setBackground(bg);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to store this information in app and after user closed and re-opened the app I still want to have custom background image.

I don't know how can I archive this.

I tried to store the Uri of the image but get some permission problems (`android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`), which is known problem.

How get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image in `onActivityResult` to storage then save the file path in `SharedPreference`s or database... So every time the user comes back, you load it and set as background

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String mFilePath;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgpath,storedpath;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    ImageView myImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
         sp=getSharedPreferences("setback", MODE_PRIVATE);
         if(sp.contains("imagepath")) {
             storedpath=sp.getString("imagepath", "");
             myImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(storedpath));
         }
    }
    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgpath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Log.d("path", imgpath);
                cursor.close();

            SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sp.edit();
                edit.putString("imagepath",imgpath);
                edit.commit();


                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgpath);

                    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
               else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
}
}
```

And this as your layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:text="Load Picture" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to put permissions to read and write external storage

Comment: I copied the code above to new project called  'TestApp', I also added read and write external storage permission on my manifest file, the code did not work. I have go to settings->apps->TestApp (locate your app name). Open it, and give it Storage permission. Now, everything works find, thanks!

Comment: Its because you are using mobile with android api higher than lollipop.. it needs run time permission.. If you add run time permissions for read and write storage, you not need to go to setting externally, it will ask in the beginning only..

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. I followed your advice; set permission at run time and code now works fine.

Comment: This is not working for me, I have copied the code and in Manifest I wrote permission for Write and Read external Storage but the image it is not shown in the view for activity_main.